# Apple Live Photo file format

Tags: ios, ios9, photokit, phlivephoto

Apple will introduce [Live Photo](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/cameras/) in iOS 9/iPhone 6s. Where is the file format documented?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016572-DontLinkElementID_2). Otherwise, here's the text:

> **Live Photos**
>
> Live Photos is a new feature of iOS 9 that allows users to capture and
>   relive their favorite moments with richer context than traditional
>   photos. When the user presses the shutter button, the Camera app
>   captures much more content along with the regular photo, including
>   audio and additional frames before and after the photo. When browsing
>   through these photos, users can interact with them and play back all
>   the captured content, making the photos come to life.
>
> iOS 9.1 introduces APIs that allow apps to incorporate playback of
>   Live Photos, as well as export the data for sharing. There is new
>   support in the Photos framework to fetch a PHLivePhoto object from the
>   PHImageManager object, which is used to represent all the data that
>   comprises a Live Photo. You can use a PHLivePhotoView object (defined
>   in the PhotosUI framework) to display the contents of a Live Photo.
>   The PHLivePhotoView view takes care of displaying the image, handling
>   all user interaction, and applying the visual treatments to play back
>   the content.
>
> You can also use PHAssetResource to access the data of a PHLivePhoto
>   object for sharing purposes. You can request a PHLivePhoto object for
>   an asset in the user’s photo library by using PHImageManager or
>   UIImagePickerController. If you have a sharing extension, you can also
>   get PHLivePhoto objects by using NSItemProvider. On the receiving side
>   of a share, you can recreate a PHLivePhoto object from the set of
>   files originally exported by the sender.
>
> **Guidelines for Displaying Live Photos**
>
> It’s important to remember that a Live Photo is still a photo. If you have to display a Live Photo in
>   an environment that doesn’t support PHLivePhotoView, it’s recommended
>   that you present it as a regular photo.
>
> Don’t display the extra frames and audio of a Live Photo separately.
>   It's important that the content of the Live Photo be presented in a
>   consistent way that uses the same visual treatment and interaction
>   model in all apps.
>
> It’s recommended that you identify a photo as a Live Photo by placing
>   the badge provided by the PHLivePhotoView class method
>   livePhotoBadgeImageWithOptions:PHLivePhotoBadgeOptionsOverContent in
>   the top-left corner of the photo.
>
> Note that there is no support for providing the visual effect that
>   users experience as they swipe through photos in the Photos app.
>
> **Guidelines for Sharing Live Photos**
>
> The data of a Live Photo is
>   exported as a set of files in a PHAssetResource object. The set of
>   files must be preserved as a unit when you upload them to a server.
>   When you rebuild a PHLivePhoto with these files on the receiver side,
>   the files are validated; loading fails if the files don’t come from
>   the same asset.
>
> If your app lets users apply effects or adjustments to a photo before
>   sharing it, be sure to apply the same adjustments to all frames of the
>   Live Photo. Alternatively, if you don’t support adjusting the entire
>   contents of a Live Photo, share it as a regular photo and show an
>   appropriate indication to the user.
>
> If your app has UI for picking photos to share, you should let users
>   play back the entire contents so they know exactly what they are
>   sharing.When selecting photos to share in your app, users should also
>   be able to turn a Live Photo off, so they can post it as a traditional
>   photo.

Answer (score 71):

A live photo has two resources. They are tied together with an asset identifier (a UUID as a string).

1. A JPEG; this must have a metadata entry for [`kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagepropertymakerappledictionary?language=objc) with `[17 : assetIdentifier]` (17 is the Apple Maker Note Asset Identifier key).
2. A Quicktime MOV encoded with H.264 at the appropriate framerate (12-15fps) and size (1080p). This MOV must have:

   - Top-level Quicktime Metadata entry for `["com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier" : assetIdentifier]`. If using `AVAsset` you can get this from `asset.metadataForFormat(AVMetadataFormatQuickTimeMetadata)`
   - Timed Metadata track with `["com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time" : 0xFF]`; The actual still image time matches up to the presentation timestamp for this metadata item. The payload seems to just be a single `0xFF` byte (aka -1) and can be ignored. If using an `AVAssetReader` you can use `CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp` to get this time.

The `assetIdentifier` is what ties the two items together and the timed metadata track is what tells the system where the still image sits in the movie timeline.

Comment: An implementation of writing such files can be found here: https://github.com/genadyo/LivePhotoDemo

Comment: Is this still the case on iOS 11 when creating HEIC files, or is the movie part wrapped up in the same .heic file as the photo part?

Comment: So the JPEG file itself does not contain the video, unlike Android's "Motion Photo", where the JPG contains the video in the same file. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 6):

Outside of the documentation, Live Photos are made up of 2 resources, an image and an mov (quicktime movie file).  So every Live Photo has 2 'actual' files connected by the wrapper of the Live Photo type.

Answer (score 2):

Live Photos is actually two files. Original JPEG Image and Full HD Video.

Answer (score 1):

Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for the format is `kUTTypeLivePhoto` / `com.apple.live-photo`

```
@available(OSX 10.12, *)
public let kUTTypeLivePhoto: CFString

/*
 *
 *  kUTTypeLivePhoto
 *
 *    Live Photo
 *
 *    UTI: com.apple.live-photo
 *
 *
 */
```

Comment: What does `kUTTypeLivePhoto` conform to? `UTTypeCopyDeclaration(kUTTypeLivePhoto)` says it conforms to nobody. It seems a bit strange.

Comment: How does this relate to `com.apple.quicktime-movie`? Does `com.apple.live-photo` encompass both a still image such as png or jpeg and a movie?

Answer (score 0):

some additional info about live photos:

1. agree, it has .mov file extension
2. it saved in directory /var/mobile/media/DCIM/100apple/ alongside
   with jpg version of photo
3. live photos can be played even on device without 3D touch (I can
   play it on my ipad 2017 via long-pressing on the photo)
4. it can be played even on old phones (such as iphone 5) even on iOS8
   if you install PhotosLive tweak