# Possible to view & edit Apple iOS Live Photos on a Windows machine, C#, or other OS?

Tags: c#, ios, iphoto, phlivephoto, apple-live-photos

Is there any way to programmatically view, manage, and edit [Apple iOS Live Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014399-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7) on a Windows-based platform?

Any detailed information on the file structure, and how to access it would be appreciated.  (Is it simply a MOV or is it an array of still images?)

(The ubiquity of Microsoft's online live.com and Apple's iOS Live Photos has made it impossible to search for the information I need. )

Comment: u need know what are these "Apple iOS Live Photos". are these "MOV or is it an array of still images" ? until u figured this out, this has nothing to do with m$ or c#

Comment: The format has been described into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format