# Google Photos API: Identify "motion photos"

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api, apple-live-photos

For media items that are "motion photos", the Google Photos API allows you to append "=dv" to the base URL of a media item to get the item as a "video/mp4".  Without the =dv, the item comes back as a "image/jpeg".  This works more or less as described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items#motion-base-urls).

What I can't figure out is how to tell whether or not a given item is a motion photo.  The metadata returned for motion photos looks to be the same as for regular photos.  Is there something I'm missing or do I need to try loading each photo as a video and handling the 404s?

Comment: Maybe this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format

Comment: @JakeHemmington Are Apple Live photos the same thing as a Motion Photo?