# Convert a video into an IOS Live Photo format without an Apple device

Tags: ios, ios10, photokit, phlivephoto, apple-live-photos

I'm currently making live/animated wallpapers for Android phones, which is pretty easy with GIF/Mp4 files. But I would also like to make the live wallpapers compatible natively with ios/iPhones. I've seen many tutorials on how to convert a video to a Live photo but they all involve some kind of app you need to install on your IPhone. Issue is, I don't own an iPhone or any iOS device to do that and apparently iOS emulators are not a thing, so my question is :

Is it possible to convert a (mp4) video to an iOs Live photo through a 3rd party ? If so, how would you do it ?
I'm pretty inexperienced with the iOS environnement so thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Well, a live photo is a container that holds both a .jpeg and a H.264-encoded .mov file. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format).

Do you have an Apple computer to do so, or do you want to create it independently from any apple hardware?

For the first case, there are a bunch of (demo) [applications](https://github.com/mzp/LoveLiver) on github you could take a look into.

For the second case, I'm not sure if anything exists.

Comment: I do have access to an Apple computer so that would be acceptable. But my particular usecase is I want to do it programmatically for 1000 gifs (or maybe mov if I convert) rather than manually 1 by 1

Comment: Did you already check this library: https://github.com/LimitPoint/LivePhoto ? To me it looks quite promising.

Comment: First requirement: **macOS 10.11 (El Capitan), 10.12 (Sierra)**