# Write Live Photo metadata to video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, apple-live-photos

According to [Apple Live Photo file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format/35286486#35286486), there are three pieces of metadata that need to be written for a JPEG and MOV to be accepted as a live photo. I can use exiftool and ffmpeg to write the necessary content identifier metadata.

For the JPEG:

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile reference.jpeg -makernotes -ContentIdentifier image.jpeg
exiftool -ContentIdentifier="$id" image.jpeg
```

Similarly, ffmpeg can be used to write the top-level Quicktime metadata with matching id.

However I'm having trouble with the timed metadata: `["com.apple.quicktime.still-image-time" : 0xFF]`.

I can't even manage to produce a copy of an existing live photo MOV file using ffmpeg that preserves the necessary timed metadata.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mov -map 0 -c copy -movflags use_metadata_tags copy.mov
```

copies the global metadata (i.e. com.apple.quicktime.content.identifier), but loses the necessary still-image-time which can be confirmed using exiftool:

```
> exiftool -G -U -ee original.mov | grep 'Still Image Time'
[QuickTime]     Still Image Time                : -1
> exiftool -G -U -ee copy.mov | grep 'Still Image Time'
>
```

How can I write the timed metadata using ffmpeg—specifically the still-image-time data?

Edit: it looks like this may be happening because ffmpeg does not know how to handle the `mebx` tag on data streams:

```
[mov @ 0x7fb232091400] Unknown hldr_type for mebx, writing dummy values
```

And ffmpeg doesn't seem to have a way to copy unknown streams. This appears to also be a problem for dealing with the `fdsc` tag in GoPro metadata streams (e.g. see https://gist.github.com/radimklaska/8974637522a751adb49db0de3be482c9#file-gopro_hevc_to_dnxhd-sh-L125), so it's often copied over as `gpmd` data, which ensures it's not overwritten with dummy values, but this trick doesn't work in the case of live photos `mebx` metadata.

Comment: Hi, I faced the same problem, did you figure this out so far?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, and I think it should be possible with the [bento4](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4edit/) tools. I've previously used this to copy the GPS metadata which is also stored in this structure, it should work in this case as well, however I don't know enough about it to get it to work.

It seems the `mebx` data is stored in `moov/trak/mdia/minf/stbl/stsd`, however I cannot get this transplanted properly.

E.g. this does not work and creates a big broken file:

```
# Get atom from original file
mp4extract moov/trak IMG_1337.MOV trak.atom

# insert into converted file
mp4edit --insert moov:trak.atom IMG_1337-converted.MOV IMG_1337-converted-metadata.MOV
```

Hope somebody can build on this.