# How to turn a photo and a video into a live photo

Tags: ios, scripting, exiftool, google-photos, apple-live-photos

At some point I uploaded the live photos from my iPhone to Google Photos, the photos were still live on Google. Then I downloaded all of those photos to my Linux Mint. They are stored on my PC now as a pair of image (JPG or HEIF in some cases I think) and a short video (MP4 or MOV). If I try to upload them back to Google Photos, they are stored there as 2 separate files (which is really annoying).

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508375/apple-live-photo-file-format), I thought about writing a script to change the metadata in the image and the video to see if when I upload them, they will show up in Google Photos as a Live Photo again.
I see that someone was trying to do something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376581/write-live-photo-metadata-to-video-using-ffmpeg).

My questions are: the metadata fields in the link don't seem to match the ones from exiftool, has anyone seen or done this? Has anyone managed to do this?